# Django websocket works on local but not in Amazon EC2 server, error during Websocket handshake

Tags: python, django, angular, amazon-ec2

I have a project in websockets with angular and django, it works fine locally with Linux, when I have deployed it to Amazon EC2 that is also Linux and did the same with Linux locally, I have attached a screenshot of the server in django in Amazon EC2 that it looks that is running ok, [server screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwvtB.png), the client that is an angular app, when I'm trying to connect to the server **this.globals.socket = new WebSocket('ws://mydomain.com.com/stocks')**, I'm getting this error **WebSocket connection to 'ws://mydomain.com.com/stocks' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404**. Do I have to configure something in nginx.conf in Amazon EC2 server?, or do I have to enable something additional in the server?. Any help or clue would really be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You are running your server on localhost (127.0.0.1:8000). It's not accessible from outside. You have to run it on a public IP or configure a proxy to route requests to your localhost server. Also do not forget to open the port to the world via EC2 management interface.

Also note that you shouldn't run your server via `./manage.py runserver` on production. You should use application WSGI server (e.g. Gunicorn) and webserver (e.g. Nginx). Check out [this good tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04). Basically you run Gunicorn which is bound to unix socket, and Nginx which proxies (`proxy_pass`) all requests to the unix socket.